# How to reference new field if it is DAC Extension

Tags: acumatica

I have a couple of new fields in Sales Order (Screen ID - SM204505). I have added these fields from customization project > Data Access. Once published this customization project all the new fields are created in SOOrder table.

Now I want to reference these new fields in my Customization Project in Visual Studio to fill some other values (i.e. add some more business logic). 
For example, there is a custom field called UsrReasonCode added to SOOrder table. And then I want to write some business logic to get this value from SOOrder and fill into some other table (i.e. Document Line item > ReasonCode)

It is working if I create Table Extension but I am not sure how to reference if I add it through DAC Extension. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference extension fields by using extension object
like that:

```
DocExt ext=PXCache<Doc>.GetExtension<DocExt>(doc);
```

This will get extension object `DocExt` related to the original Doc object. So you can reference extension fields like `ext.UsrField`.

To read more about that you can download T300 training from acumatica university

Comment: Found the same. Thank you. However, that doesnot work if we add custom fields through Customization Project > Data Access, because it adds the class in Project's App_RuntimeCode folder which we cannot reference.