# Acumatica Weirdness with PXCacheExtension/PXGraphExtension

Tags: acumatica

I have a Cache Extension:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
    {
        [PXBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sales Promotion", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]

        public virtual bool? UsrSalesPromotion { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrSalesPromotion : IBqlField { }
    }
}
```

and a Graph Extension:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected void SOLine_RowSelecting(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
        if (salesOrderEntry == null)
            return;

        SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLineExt>(salesOrderEntry);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<soLineExt.usrSalesPromotion>(cache, salesOrderEntry, false);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that SOLineExt is not found which I think is because the cache extention was created through Project Customization which puts the resulting .cs file in the Runtime_App folder ([How to reference new field if it is DAC Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351055/how-to-reference-new-field-if-it-is-dac-extension), see last comment).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is that I can't read what I type. Iwas using soLineExt instead of SOLineExt. It would be nice to have a way for VS/Resharper to not complain about not finding SOLineExt, but it is not imperative.